# Would it be wrong to give a quality answer to a poor question?

Tags: discussion, questions

While browsing on the SO site, I sometimes come across questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283382/python-script-to-convert-strings-from-hex-to-bin-contained-in-a-txt). It is clear that the question is asking for someone to write code for them, which is probably not an appropriate question type for SO.

I wondered though wether answering questions such as that one would be frowned upon by the community. If I were to say, write a quick example program that answered his question, would that be appropriate? Yes, the question its-self is may be poor, but wouldn't it be fine if you were just answering the question?

Comment: There is even a badge for that, having like +5/10 on a -5 question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be wrong to give a quality answer to a poor question?

Technically there is nothing **official** (currently) that forbids answering any question, on-topic or otherwise, other than question closure.

You are not **required** to be able to determine whether a question is off-topic or not.

> It is clear that the question is asking for someone to write code for them, which is probably not an appropriate question type for SO.

That statement is not entirely correct. Questions asking how to do something, whether they show research effort or not, are on-topic; however, they *can* be overly broad, which would make them off-topic.

> I wondered though wether answering questions such as that one would be frowned upon by the community

Now you're getting somewhere, the **community** as a whole seems to currently lean more towards frowning upon answering off-topic questions for a few reasons, one of those being that it can prevent deletion of off-topic questions.

<sup>More: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)</sup>

> Yes, the question its-self is may be poor, but wouldn't it be fine if you were just answering the question?

In summary, yes there is *technically* nothing wrong with answering any question at all, you are in no way obliged to not answer any open question you feel like answering, as long as it is in fact an answer and it does not have severe content or formatting problems.

Note that, with sufficient reputation, users can (and probably will) downvote and possibly vote to delete such answers if they feel that the answers are not useful.